# ElasticSearch simple match

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm strangling with simple query. 
I want to match exac value - skip all ES analyzing process, i need equivalent of "WHERE key = 'SOME-KEY'".

My field definition is looks like this:

```
"url_key": {
"type": "text",
"copy_to": [
"search",
"spelling"
],
"analyzer": "standard"
},
```

I tried

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "url_key": "SOME-URL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

returns not exac match

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "url_key": "SOME-URL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns 0 hits

Changing field type to "keyword" will make "match" work properly in this case? 
Can i make proper query without changing "type" for url_key field?

Comment: I am trying to use `term` query on your data and will keep you posted., btw by looking at your field name looks like you want to store the `url` and for which elasticsearch has inbuilt tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html

Comment: sorry didn't notice you already tried `term` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify to use the keyword data type as `match` query is analyzed and by default on `text` field `standard analyzer` is applied which breaks tokens on whitespace etc.

As you are storing the `urls` in your text field https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html is built for this purpose only which would handle the edge cases and should be used instead of `keyword` field for storing `urls`.

**Working example**

### Index Setting and Mapping

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "url_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "url_key": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "url_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
    "url_key" : "http://www.example.com"
}
```

### Search query same as yours

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "url_key": "http://www.example.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "url",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "url_key": "http://www.example.com"
                }
            }
        ]
```